# Не работает сервер и клиент на Android

Tags: java, android

Нашёл примеры сервера и клиента на android, но почему-то примеры не работают, хотя все верно. Я подумал, что возможно проблема связана с тем, что я запускаю оба приложения на эмуляторах. Можете подсказать с чем это может быть связано?

В логах клиента пишет:
Connection refused

Использую локальный адрес: 192.168.1.45

Код сервера:

```
package com.example.omen.serverforcofe;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by Girish Bhalerao on 5/4/2017.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private Button buttonStartReceiving;
    private Button buttonStopReceiving;
    private TextView textViewDataFromClient;
    private boolean end = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonStartReceiving = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start_receiving);
        buttonStopReceiving = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop_receiving);
        textViewDataFromClient = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_data_from_client);

        buttonStartReceiving.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonStopReceiving.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void startServerSocket() {

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            private String stringData = null;

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9002);

                    while (!end) {
                        //Server is waiting for client here, if needed
                        Socket s = ss.accept();
                        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());

                        stringData = input.readLine();
                        output.println("FROM SERVER - " + stringData.toUpperCase());
                        output.flush();

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        updateUI(stringData);
                        if (stringData.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP")) {
                            end = true;
                            output.close();
                            s.close();
                            break;
                        }

                        output.close();
                        s.close();
                    }
                    ss.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
        thread.start();
    }

    private void updateUI(final String stringData) {

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String s = textViewDataFromClient.getText().toString();
                if (stringData.trim().length() != 0)
                    textViewDataFromClient.setText(s + "\n" + "From Client : " + stringData);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_start_receiving:

                startServerSocket();
                buttonStartReceiving.setEnabled(false);
                buttonStopReceiving.setEnabled(true);
                break;

            case R.id.btn_stop_receiving:

                //stopping server socket logic you can add yourself
                buttonStartReceiving.setEnabled(true);
                buttonStopReceiving.setEnabled(false);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Код клиента:

```
package com.example.omen.clientforcofe;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by Girish Bhalerao on 5/4/2017.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView mTextViewReplyFromServer;
    private EditText mEditTextSendMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

        mEditTextSendMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_send_message);
        mTextViewReplyFromServer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_reply_from_server);

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btn_send:
                sendMessage(mEditTextSendMessage.getText().toString());
                break;
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage(final String msg) {

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    //Replace below IP with the IP of that device in which server socket open.
                    //If you change port then change the port number in the server side code also.
                    Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.45", 9002);

                    OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

                    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);

                    output.println(msg);
                    output.flush();
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    final String st = input.readLine();

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            String s = mTextViewReplyFromServer.getText().toString();
                            if (st.trim().length() != 0)
                                mTextViewReplyFromServer.setText(s + "\nFrom Server : " + st);
                        }
                    });

                    output.close();
                    out.close();
                    s.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Полные логи ошибок добавьте

Answer (score 1):

1. попробуйте запустить сервер на реальном устройстве, и с эмулятора (клиента) подключится. Также можно будет посмотреть IP устройства.
2. попробуйте на стороне сервера "пробить" его IP, может там 127.0.0.1?
3. проверьте что в программе есть доступ в Internet (android.permission.INTERNET)